# Получить код ответа состояния сервера HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

Метод справляется со своей задачей, только мне не нравится как это всё записано, уверен можно сделать красивее, и увеличить читабельность кода.

```
public int GetStatusCode(string url)
{
    int statusCode = 0; // хочу избавиться от объявления здесь.
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.Accept = @"*/*";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Response == null)
            throw;
        statusCode = (int)((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode;
    }
    return statusCode;
}
```

Что-то на подобии этого не предлагайте:

```
public int GetStatusCode(string url, int statusCode = 0)
```

Оптимизированный код должен работать на версии .Net 4.0, спасибо.

Comment: а что вас не устраивает?

Comment: @VladimirT в коде есть комментарий, объявление `int statusCode`

Comment: А что вам мешает? удалите строку с status code и возвращайте в блоке `try`:
`return (int)response.StatusCode;`

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F. вы дали комментарий когда я дал ответ)))

Comment: почему бы не сделать метод асинхронным?

Comment: @tym32167 да правы, если не сложно приведите пример.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример асинхронного вызова

```
public async Task<int> GetStatusCode(string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.Accept = @"*/*";

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            return (int)response.StatusCode;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Response == null)
            throw;
        return (int)((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode;
    }
}
```

Ну, или, например, так

```
async Task<int> GetStatus(string uri)
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false
    };

    using (var cl = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(@"*/*"));
        var response = await cl.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, uri),
             HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        return (int)response.StatusCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а я как раз не знал как обернуть в `using` - прямо читаете мысли, теперь понял где была ошибка `IDisposable`.

Comment: @SergeyUsick пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 4):

`WebResponse` реализует интерфейс `IDisposable`, поэтому желательно его диспозить. Проще всего это сделать, обернув код в `using`.

```
public int GetStatusCode(string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.Accept = @"*/*";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            return (int)response.StatusCode;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Response == null)
            throw;
        return (int)((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Всего лишь перенести return:

```
public int GetStatusCode(string url)
{

  try
  {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.Accept = @"*/*";
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var rescode = (int)response.StatusCode;
    response.Close();
    return rescode;
  }
  catch (WebException ex)
  {
    if (ex.Response == null)
        throw;
    return (int)((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode;
  }

}
```

Comment: `response.Close()` после `return`не сработает.

Comment: после `return (int)response.StatusCode;` выполнится  `response.Close();` ?

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F. поправил, согласен с вами.

Comment: @SergeyUsick комментарий ранее.